# Tabbar controller is not showing all the tabs

Tags: ios, xcode6, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using TabbarController and Storyboard in my app. I have added five view controllers to TabbarController. The problem is all tabs are visible in Storyboard but when I run the application, only four tabs are visible.

Here is the screenshot of TabbarController in storyboard.

[image]

Here is the screenshot of the page in the device.

[image]

In very rare cases all five tabs are appeared. I don't know what is the problem. Help me if anyone got through the same problem or anyone know how to fix this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the iPhone simulator has fixed my problem. Deleting and reinstalling the app doesn't fix this. If anyone is facing this issue, just reset the simulator.